# jqgrid Search with complex objects

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

my colModel object is a json serialized object that represent the following `MovingRecord` class

```
public class CompanyData {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public string CompetenceArea { get; set; }
}

public class MovingRecord {
    public int MovingRecordID { get; set; }
    public CompanyData FromCompanyData { get; set; }
    public CompanyData ToCompanyData { get; set; }
    public float FTE { get; set; }
}
```

In the jqGrid configuration I have the following colModel:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'FromCompanyData.Code', index: 'FromCompanyData.Code', width: 70, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'FromCompanyData.Segment', index: 'FromCompanyData.Segment', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'FromCompanyData.CompetenceArea', index: 'FromCompanyData.CompetenceArea', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'ToCompanyData.Code', index: 'ToCompanyData.Code', width: 70, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'ToCompanyData.Segment', index: 'ToCompanyData.Segment', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'ToCompanyData.CompetenceArea', index: 'ToCompanyData.CompetenceArea', width: 170, sortable: false, align: 'left', search: true, template: colTextTemplate },
    { name: 'FTE', index: 'FTE', width: 60, sortable: false, align: 'right', search: true, formatter: 'number', template: colFloatTemplate }
],
```

This works exactly as expected. Unfortunately the problem is when I try to search on those field. Because of the nature of the record itself the members `FromCompanyData/ToCompanyData` can be nullable objects.

The search is activated with the following code:

```
grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + pagerID, {
    caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-search", position: "last", title: "Advanced search filters",
    onClickButton: function () {
        grid.jqGrid('searchGrid', 
            { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'cn'], closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true, recreateFilter: true });
    }
});
```

when I try to search I always receive the following error `"{Field Name} : the field is required".`

Any help on how to solve this problem?
Thanks

**EDIT:** 
As per Oleg comment, this is the definition of `colTextTemplate`

```
var colTextTemplate = {
    sorttype: 'text',
    align: 'left',
    search: true,
    stype: 'text',
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'cn'] },
    searchrules: { required: true }
};
```

I have tried to remove the `required: true` option and experienced a different behaviour. If I remove this option the original error disappear but the built filter does not include the data field even if I fill it with some text.
For example, the filter is like the following one

```
{
    "_search":true,
    "nd":1391184286612,
    "rows":9999,
    "page":1,
    "sidx":"MovingRecordID",
    "sord":"asc",
    "filters":"{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"FromCompanyData.Code\",\"op\":\"eq\",\"data\":\"\"}]}","searchField":"","searchString":"","searchOper":""}
```

Comment: could you include the definition of `colTextTemplate`?

Comment: @Oleg: sure. Please have a look at my edit!

Comment: @Oleg: No news for me? :(

Comment: I forgot about the question totally :-(. I'll post short answer with my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last update makes all still not quite clear for me. I think that you should remove `required: true` property from `searchrules` (or set to `required: false`). The problem with empty data seems to me **another problem**. It's a bug in the current implementation of jqGrid. I posted [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/551) my suggetion to fix the problem. [Here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/ba942a5786a0f901ed1a75fbbe08eee72c7e9664) are the most important parts of required changes. The main idea is: triggering of `change` event (see [the line](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/ba942a5786a0f901ed1a75fbbe08eee72c7e9664#diff-382b3649283911e1a5c64f3ec00e4968R229)) before usage of the data from the searching dialog. `setTimeout` should be removed additionally (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/ca6b9b1aec7373346148f4b6704e236304d57ba8)) to use the current data from the searching dialog. [The referenced pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/551) is merged to the main code of jqGrid on github about two months before, but the last released version 4.5.4 contains still the bug. I recommend you to make described modifications in your copy of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. making the modifications you've suggested it seems to work. Hope that those modifications will be soon added to the next release. Thanks very much for helping. Great job :)

Comment: more info on your update. I am experiencing that the change event where I have removed the `setTimeout` function is not firing when the user inpute text. But it fires correctly when I click again on the input element to give him focus...

Comment: @Lorenzo: 1) As I wrote, the pull is already merged to the main code of jqGrid. So the next release of jqGrid will have the described changes. 2) removing `setTimeout` is important in case of usage jQuery UI Autocomplete in the field only. If one don't remove `setTimeout` and use jQuery UI Autocomplete and one use `searchOnEnter: true` option then one can have the following bug: one types quickly some text in some input field and type "Enter" at the end. In the case the data used for searching will don't use the entered data. My changes should fix the problem. You are welcome!